# In a webpage, why hovering a hover navbar make changes on html index?

Tags: web-scraping, navbar

I'm trying to scraping a webpage which is my trialtask for now, but it's my first time, I wrote some script by using python bs4 to gather information and used some tools but I can't fix the navbar problem. It's written by bootstrap forsure but for my task I have to pull it from that header. How can I scarpe the navbar operationally or should I code another replica, I'm researching for a 2days I'm not that experienced at scraping. For mainpage.html all the css+js written together. Is this the jQuery could be the problem to me?

[While nothovering in inspectation mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH2mh.png)
[While hovering in inspectation mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNnaM.png)
Using GoogleChrome v111.0.5563.65

Comment: Can you share the domain/site you're scraping?

Comment: Of course!
[link](https://www.classcentral.com/)
I couldn't scrape the navbar
@ConorReid